# Can MARS regression be used for classification?

Tags: regression, nonlinear-regression, mars

I am dealing with a data set in which I have to classify between a diseased and a non-diseased individual. I was wondering if it is possible to adapt the MARS regression (Multivariate adaptive regression spline) to use it for classification tasks. Thank you very much and best regards.

Comment: I doubt you meant to imply forced-choice classification.  This should be called a probability model.  See https://fharrell.com/post/classification

Answer (score 2):

Earth (generic name) is just a way to make nonlinear basis functions $f_i$. Once you have those basis functions, you can apply a link function $g$ for a GLM, such as logistic regression or probit regression.

$$
\text{EARTH: }
\mathbb E[Y\vert X] = \sum_{i=1}^k\beta_if_i(X)\\
\text{GLM EARTH: }
g(\mathbb E[Y\vert X]) = \sum_{i=1}^k\beta_if_i(X)
$$

Comment: But doesn't the method for finding/selecting those basis functions optimize mse? Is there a way to select the bases themselves based on GLM losses? (Cursorily I suspect that that loses the fastness of MARS exploiting RSS updates instead of full recomputation?)

Comment: @BenReiniger The equations in random variables for a mathematical model are so logically dependent on choices of objective functions such as mean squared error. For example, there is nothing stopping me from using [NUTS](https://arxiv.org/abs/1111.4246) instead of least squares.

Answer (score 0):

**Yes, MARS (and Bayesian MARS) is a powerful tool for multi-class classification.** Check out the R package [$\texttt{cbass}$](https://CRAN.R-project.org/package=cbass), which can be found on CRAN. This package extends the approach of Denison and Holmes (2003) to the multi-class classification setting. A paper accompanying this R package is expected to be published soon, and I will reference it here whenever it becomes available.

---

MARS regression, originally proposed by Friedman (1991), has been successfully applied to regression many times over the years (see Kooperberg, Bose & Stone (1997) for an early reference).

Holmes & Denison (2003) tackle the problem of 2-class classification using Bayesian MARS (Denison, Mallick & Smith (1998)). Given a $p$-dimensional vector of predictors (standardized for simplicity), $x \in [0,1]^p$, the response variable $y\in \{0,1\}$ is modeled as
$$P(y_i=1 | x_i) = g(\eta_i)$$
where
$$\eta_i = \beta_0 + \sum_{m=1}^M\beta_m\prod_{j=1}^{J_m}\left(s_{jm}\left[x_{u_{jm}} - \theta_{jm}\right]_+\right).$$
The function $[\cdot]_+ = \max(\cdot, 0)$ is the *rectified linear unit* (ReLU), $s_{jm} \in \{-1, 1\}$ is called a *sign*, $\theta_{jm} \in (0, 1)$ is called a *knot*, and $u_{jm}\in \{1,\ldots,p\}$ selects which variables are activated in each basis function (i.e., each term of the sum).

In classification, the most popular choice of link function $g()$ is the *logit link*, but Holmes and Denison show that using a probit link ($g(a) = \Phi(a)$ where $\Phi()$ is the standard normal CDF) leads to substantial computational advantages. Without going into too much detail, the probit link model can be represented by adding a set of $n$ latent variables, one for each training data point. Only by adding these normally distributed latent variables, can the coefficients $\beta$ can be integrated out of the model. This leads to drastically better mixing of the MCMC, by allowing for large changes to the model (e.g., by removing, adding, or modifying a basis function), without needing to fuss about a complicated trans-dimensional proposal distribution for the coefficients. See Holmes and Denison (2003) for more details or see Francom et al. (2019) for a modern discussion in the regression setting.

---

##### References

Frank Marrs and Devin Francom (2023). cbass: Classification -- Bayesian Adaptive Smoothing Splines. R package version 0.1. https://CRAN.R-project.org/package=cbass

Friedman, J. H. (1991). Multivariate adaptive regression splines. The annals of statistics, 19(1), 1-67.

Kooperberg, C., Bose, S., & Stone, C. J. (1997). Polychotomous regression. Journal of the American Statistical Association, 92(437), 117-127.

Holmes, C. C., & Denison, D. G. T. (2003). Classification with bayesian MARS. Machine Learning, 50, 159-173.

Denison, D. G., Mallick, B. K., & Smith, A. F. (1998). Bayesian mars. Statistics and Computing, 8, 337-346.

Francom, D., Sansó, B., Bulaevskaya, V., Lucas, D., & Simpson, M. (2019). Inferring atmospheric release characteristics in a large computer experiment using Bayesian adaptive splines. Journal of the American Statistical Association.